# Необходимость валидации сущностей, извлеченных из базы данных

Tags: c#, валидация, entity, ddd

Всем доброго времени суток)
Разрабатываю систему с использованием DDD.

В системе есть 2 модуля:

1. Модуль конфигурации. Он занимается регистрацией новых устройств: само устройство, его модель и прочие параметры.
2. Модуль проверки устройства на дефекты.

1. Каждый тип устройства описывает конкретный класс-сущность (entity). При этом при создании объекта класса-сущности необходимо производить валидацию его параметров. Регистрация нового устройства в системе заканчивается его сохранением в базе данных с использованием соответствующего репозитория (repository).
2. В модуле проверки выбранное из списка устройство загружается в программу из базы данных. При помощи соответствующего репозитория на основе идентификатора возвращается устройство для проверки на неисправности. На выходе репозитория в диагностику загружается соответствующий объект класса-сущности устройства. Однако для создания такого объекта необходимо проводить его валидацию.

Возникает вопрос: насколько необходимо проводить валидацию извлеченной из базы данных информации, если изначально в базу данных записывается верная информации о сущности? Сама валидация осуществляется классом-валидатором, встраивающимся в соответствующий объект-сущность устройства.

Может быть я что-либо совсем не так понимаю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В базе нужно хранить уже достоверную и правильную информацию, чтобы сохранялась целостность данных. То есть что ты именно будешь верифицировать при извлечении из бд, я не понимаю. Проверять данные на корректность, нужно обязательно (!!) перед сохранением в БД.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Заранее предупреждаю, что обсуждаю вопрос в контексте DDD.
Допустим в программу на диагностику добавлен объект класса Car. При создании объекта класса Car осуществляется валидация параметров. Валидация определена в доменной модели.
Репозиторий при обращении к базе возвращает объект класса Car на основе запроса к базе данных. Поскольку валидация осуществляется в самом классе Car, то осуществляется фактически валидация уже корректных данных. Это меня смущает.

Comment: У тебя есть класс `Car` в котором есть по мимо свойств некий объект-поле класса `CarValidator`, верно? Если так, то в чем тогда сомнение, ведь `Car` связан с `CarValidator` связью _ассоциация_, а не _агрегация_.

Comment: Используется агрегация, чтобы при создании объекта можно было задать правила валидации. Просто смущает необходимость проверки валидных данных. Хотя, в таком случае можно задать валидатор, определяющий объект как полностью корректный на случай извлечения информации из базы. Смущает только то, что такой объект-сущность может в дальнейшем иметь некорректные состояния. В таком случае, агрегацию объекта-валидатора лучше заменить композицией. Однако тогда класс Car будет менее гибким в плане валидации. Ее невозможно будет переопределить, не изменив класс Car. Но, думаю, это вопрос компромисса)

Comment: Вы бы немного кода показали, а то приходиться догадываться, что, да как у Вас там. Говоря об _агрегации_, имеется ввиду, что сначала создается `объект-валидатор`, затем он конфигурируется и передается в конструктор класса-сущность?

Comment: Да. Про валидатор Вы все правильно поняли.

Answer (score 1):

Я полностью согласен с @ImZ в том что при восстановлении из БД сущности валидировать не надо. Однако, проверять надо не перед сохранением в БД, а при попытке изменить сущность. Т.е. более правильно, когда нельзя привести сущность в невалидное состояние передав неправильное значение. Для этого сущность должна проводить проверку на корректность значений задаваемых через публичный интерфейс.
Все это приводит к двум выводам:

1. Сущность сохраняемая в БД априори валидна и повторная валидация не
   требуется.
2. Если используется не тупой объект с сеттерами и
   геттерами, то вполне ожидаемо, что часть полей представляющих
   состояние объекта не будет представлено в публичном интерфейсе. И
   чтобы не идти на нарушение инкапсуляции добавляя геттеры и сеттеры,
   необходимы механизмы инициализации объекта минуя публичный
   интерфейс.

Т.о. задача сохранения и восстановления в/из БД это чтение и последующая запись некоторого приватного состояния в объект.